# Exporting/Importing a JSON file via Jackson-2.9.7

Tags: java, json, jackson

Heyyo,

I'm currently working on a project where the user should be able to import/export the program data into a JSON file (of type `TreeMap<String, List<Observation>>` , where Observation is a class containing `LocalDate date` and `int value`)

To achieve the export-part, I have used some of the Jackson 2.9.7 JAR files, to gain access to the *ObjectMapper* and thus export the data into a JSON file. **Works!**

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.writeValue(file, handler.get(LocalDate.MIN, LocalDate.MAX));
```

To achieve the import-part however, I have again used the Jackson 2.9.7 JAR files, to gain access to the Object mapper, which again, **Works!**

```
byte[] rawJson = new byte[dStream.available()];
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
dStream.readFully(rawJson);                            
map = mapper.readValue(rawJson, TreeMap.class);
```

However, when I try to add the items I have now imported into a temporary map, the structure is no longer what I would expect. Instead, it seems to have converted it into a LinkedHashMap with several Entries, and thus I can't simply use the `Observation` class. I'm guessing it is because I am using `TreeMap.class` when reading it, though after some attempts, I can't say I know how to proceed.

[image: The values of the imported data]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `TypeReference`:

write:

```
TypeReference<Map<String, List<Observation>>> typeRef = 
new TypeReference<Map<String, List<Observation>>>() {};
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.writerFor(typeRef).writeValue(file, handler.get(LocalDate.MIN, LocalDate.MAX));
```

read:

```
byte[] rawJson = new byte[dStream.available()];
TypeReference<Map<String, List<Observation>>> typeRef = 
new TypeReference<Map<String, List<Observation>>>() {};
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
dStream.readFully(rawJson);                            
map = mapper.readValue(rawJson, typeRef);
```

Comment: Tried this, and while it took me forward, I am now facing a LocalDate-related issue where there is no default constructor. I found [this](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8) but doesn't seem to be doing much.

Comment: What about `@JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateTimeSerializer.class)` and `@JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateTimeDeserializer.class)` with appropriate properties of the `Observation`

Comment: I now got past that error, I simply had used the wrong file apparently. However, now I'm basically back to square 1: LinkedHashMap cannot be converted to Map when running the line `map = mapper.readValue(rawJson, typeRef)`

Comment: did you try create a custom deserializer?

Comment: I have not, though I'm thinking about it.

Comment: share the result once you'll try this, please

Comment: Issue resolved! I had mistakenly declared the temporary map as TreeMap and the TypeReference as Map, and I guess that confused it. Nonetheless, I'll mark your reply as the answer! Thanks!